# Looping through a .zip file to open an Excel file, can't get file extension?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a directory with .zip files and pull out the file which is an Excel type file having specific string in the name. I can see the files within .zip having .xlsx extension, but why I try to get this extension name (`file_ext`) using `GetExtensionName`, it's empty. Here is a slice of my code:

```
'Create instance of the shell application
Set obj_app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Get the .zip file
Set obj_file = obj_app.Namespace((str_zip_file)).Items
'Loop through each file within the .zip file
For Each obj_stream In obj_file
    str_file = obj_stream.Name
    If obj_stream.Type Like "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" And InStr(str_file, "ESG") Then
        Set obj_target = obj_app.Namespace(obj_subfolder.Path)
        'If it's an Excel file, set the file name to `str_excel_file` and exit the loop
        str_excel_file = str_file
        obj_target.CopyHere obj_stream
        file_ext = LCase(obj_fso.GetExtensionName(obj_subfolder.Path & "\" & str_file))
        Exit For
    End If
Next obj_stream
```

Also, when pulled out of .zip into the directory when actual .zip is placed (done by `obj_target.CopyHere obj_stream`) it appears as being without '.xlsx' extension. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the `Windows Explorer>>View>>Show/hide>>File name extensions` setting. It should be checked so as to have extensions visible in explorer.

Comment: Thanks @shrivallabha.redij, really, I wouldn't come up to this :)

Comment: Worth noting that even with extensions hidden in Explorer, `obj_stream.Path` will still include the file extension, so `obj_fso.GetExtensionName(obj_stream.Path)` will still work.